Computing fixpoint logic in Cuda
I'm new to Cuda and I try to parallelize several fixpoint operations.
The problem is that computing the fixpoint can vary massively in length, which is not the best solution for SIMT.
I try to cut the algorithm in smaller peaces that can be parallized better, but I struggle with the logic how to connect the smaller parts together.
The original algorithms in pseudo code is something like this:
constant data[big][big];

vec fixpoint(int in) {
    vec v;
    v.push_back(in)
    start = 0
    while start < len(vec) {
        current = v[start]
        for i = 1..n(current, data) {
            if foo(data, v, current)
                v.push_back(data[something])
            if fixpoint_condition(data, v)
                return vec
        }
        start = start + 1
    }
}

int main() {
    for i = 1..M {
        v = fixpoint(i)
        domesomething(v)
    }
}

So the main function calls fixpoint for all numbers 1..M.
This is one point where I can parallelize.
But given that different calls to fixpoint can have quite some runtime differences I do not think that is a good idea to have different calls to fixpoint in a warp, as a lot of threads will not do something useful as they already reached a fixpoint while other threads are still searching for the fixpoint.
So I would like to cut down my kernel even more to something like this:
        current = v[start]
        for i = 1..n(current, data) {
            if foo(data, v, current)
                v.push_back(data[something])
            if fixpoint_condition(data, v)
                return vec
        }

So each thread has a vector v (unfortunately I probably have to use a static size preallocated) in global memory
and can execute the inner for loop for one element in v, thereby extending v and/or finding a fixpoint.
Now I can massicely parallelize these threads for the numbers 1..M. And they all have a similar runtime (n(current,data))which should utilize my GPU best.
My Problem now is to encode the outer fixpoint enumeration.
When a thread is finished the CPU (or maybe GPU, maybe barrier?) would need to check if the fixpoint had been reached (a flag in v was set maybe) or if new elements have been added to v. If no fixpoint has been reached a new thread with start+1 has to be scheduled to continue the search for the fixpoint for that particular number.
How can I program this logic with CUDA.
Depending on the outcome of a thread, I either want to schedule another thread that continues to work on the results of the old thread. Or to stop and use the result.
I thought about using cuda evnts to synchronize with the CPU after a thread is finished. But as each thread would need to have a different event, I think this is a bad idea. Also, cudaEventSynchronize needs the event as a parameter, but I would like to be called back for whatever thread/event finished first (and second, third etc...) so I can check if a new thread needs to be scheduled or not.
Anyone any ideas? I do not think that this kind of problem is so uncommon, I would guess that in simulation, maybe raycasting etc... you would have fixpoint operations that have different runtimes. I'm open to specific suggestions of barrier usage and general sketches.

You are right that warp divergence due to the while is bad, but why not distribute them among warps instead of threads? It might be possible to nicely parallelize the inner for among the lanes of the warp using warp primitives (or their abstractions in the Cooperative Groups API).

Thank you for this hint. This does not solve my dynamic parallelism problem but might be a nice way to spread the load even better onto the cores. Thank you very much.

I figured that you can actually asynchronously launch kernels from within a kernel with CDP2.
Calling a kernel from a kernel
https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cuda-dynamic-parallelism
With this it should be actually possible to check the result and dynamically decide to continue the fixpoint search inside the kernel.
(PSEUDO CODE)
constant data[big][big];

__global__ void subtask(int* data, vec v, int current) {
    for i = 1..n(current, data) {
        if foo(data, v, current)
            v.push_back(data[something])
    }  
}

__global__ void recursion(int* data, vec v, int index) {
    subtask(data, vec, index)
    if !fixpoint_condition(data, v)
        <<<1,1, cudaStreamTailLaunch>>>subtask(data, v, index+1)
    
}

__global__ void fixpoint(int* data) {
    index = threadId.x;
    
    __global__ vec v;
    v.push_back(data[index])
    start = 0
    recursion(data, v, 0)
}

int main() {
        <<<1, M>>>fixpoint(data)
}

The fixpoint kernel just starts the whole progress for each number M.
The recursion function does change the data and then decides if it continues the search using CDP2 and a tailLaunch, scheduling another task rigth afterwords. This means that the subtasks can hopefully be aligned in warps. And new iterations in the former while loop do get a new thread. All this without the need to communicate with the CPU.
One downside might be that vec will need to be stored in global memory as different threads will need to constantly access this memory, and there will be no guarantee that these threads are in a block.
